# Using awk to count number of row group

Tags: awk

I have a data set: (file.txt)

```
X    Y
1    a
2    b
3    c
10   d
11   e
12   f
15   g
20   h     
25   i
30   j
35   k
40   l
41   m
42   n
43   o
46   p
```

I want to add two columns which are Up10 and Down10,

- Up10: From (X) to (X-10) count of row.
- Down10 : From (X) to (X+10)
  count of row

For example:

```
X    Y    Up10    Down10    
35   k     3        5
```

- For Up10; 35-10 X=35 X=30 X=25 Total = 3 row
- For Down10; 35+10 X=35 X=40 X=41 X=42 X=42 Total = 5 row

Desired Output:

```
X    Y    Up10    Down10
1    a     1        5
2    b     2        5
3    c     3        4
10   d     4        5
11   e     5        4
12   f     5        3
15   g     4        3
20   h     5        3
25   i     3        3
30   j     3        3
35   k     3        5
40   l     3        5
41   m     3        4
42   n     4        3
43   o     5        2
46   p     5        1
```

This is the Pierre François' solution: Thanks again @Pierre François

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "X\tY\tUp10\tDown10"}
(NR == FNR) && (FNR > 1){a[$1] = $1 + 0}
(NR > FNR) && (FNR > 1){ 
  up = 0; upl = $1 - 10
  down = 0; downl = $1 + 10
  for (i in a) { i += 0 # tricky: convert i to integer
    if ((i >= upl) && (i <= $1)) {up++}
    if ((i >= $1) && (i <= downl)) {down++}
  }
  print $1, $2, up, down;
}
' file.txt file.txt > file-2.txt
```

But when i use this command for 13GB data, it takes too long.

I have used this way for 13GB data again:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} {x=y=FNR;while(--x in a&&$1-10<a[x]){} while(++y in a&&$1+10>a[y]){} print $0,FNR-x,y-FNR}
' file.txt file.txt > file-2.txt
```

When file-2.txt reaches 1.1GB it is frozen. I am waiting several hours, but i can not see finish of command and final output file.

Note: I am working on Gogole cloud. Machine type
e2-highmem-8 (8 vCPUs, 64 GB memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single pass awk that keeps the sliding window of 10 last records and uses that to count the ups and downs. For symmetricy's sake there should be `delete`s in the `END` but I guess a few extra array elements in memory isn't gonna make a difference:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
NR==1 {
    print $1,$2,"Up10","Down10"
}
NR>1 {
    a[NR]=$1
    b[NR]=$2

    for(i=NR-9;i<=NR;i++) {
        if(a[i]>=a[NR]-10&&i>=2)
            up[NR]++
        if(a[i]<=a[NR-9]+10&&i>=2)
            down[NR-9]++
    }
}
NR>10 {
    print a[NR-9],b[NR-9],up[NR-9],down[NR-9]
    delete a[NR-9]
    delete b[NR-9]
    delete up[NR-9]
    delete down[NR-9]
}
END {
    for(nr=NR+1;nr<=NR+9;nr++) {
        for(i=nr-9;i<=nr;i++)
            if(a[i]<=a[nr-9]+10&&i>=2&&i<=NR)
                down[nr-9]++
        print a[nr-9],b[nr-9],up[nr-9],down[nr-9]
   }
}' file
```

Output:

```
X       Y       Up10    Down10
1       a       1       5
2       b       2       5
...
35      k       3       5
...
43      o       5       2
46      p       5       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another single pass approach with a sliding window

```
awk '
NR == 1 { next } # skip the header
NR == 2 { min = max = cur = 1; X[cur] = $1; Y[cur] = $2; next }

{   X[++max] = $1; Y[max] = $2
    if (X[cur] >= $1 - 10) next
    for (; X[cur] + 10 < X[max]; ++cur) {
        for (; X[min] < X[cur] - 10; ++min) {
            delete X[min]
            delete Y[min]
        }   
        print X[cur], Y[cur], cur - min + 1, max - cur
    }
}

END {
    for (; cur <= max; ++cur) {
        for (; X[min] < X[cur] - 10; ++min);
        for (i = max; i > cur && X[cur] + 10 < X[i]; --i);
        print X[cur], Y[cur], cur - min + 1, i - cur + 1 
    }
}
' file
```

The script assumes the `X` column is ordered numerically.